# How to run jQuery slideshow function for each elements separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have simple jQuery slideshow, that allows me change images on click (no prev/next buttons, no preload, nothing else, it's very simple). The code only read alt text and use it as description. The code works perfect, but I can't use two slideshow divs on the same page (i need 2 or more). I try to use .each function, but it's doesn't work for me.

**Could you please help me to run slideshow functions for any divs with the same class independently?**

Code with one slideshow div (works fine): http://jsfiddle.net/6PX22/
Code with two slideshow divs (works wrong): http://jsfiddle.net/6PX22/1/

```
$(function() {
    var currentImage = 0;

    $('.slideshow img').not(':first').hide(0);
    var imagesCounter = $('.slideshow img').length;
    $('.images-counter').text(imagesCounter);
    $('.slideshow_comment').text($('.slideshow img').eq(currentImage).attr("alt"));

    $('.slideshow img').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slideshow img').eq(currentImage).hide(0);
        currentImage = currentImage >= $('.slideshow img').length-1 ? 0 : currentImage+1;
        $('.slideshow img').eq(currentImage).show(0);  
    $('.current-image-counter').text(currentImage+1);

    $('.slideshow_comment').text($('.slideshow img').eq(currentImage).attr("alt"));
    }); 
});


<div class="slideshow">
    <p><span class="current-image-counter">1</span>/<span class="images-counter">1</span></p>
    <img src="./s images/1.jpg" alt="text 01">
    <img src="./s images/2.jpg" alt="text 2">
    <img src="./s images/3.jpg" alt="text 3">
    <img src="./s images/4.jpg" alt="text 4">
    <img src="./s images/5.jpg" alt="text 5">
    <p class="slideshow_comment"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer updated (cleaned up and fully commented). I restructured it a little to make it more obvious what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the clicked slideshow, rather than every slideshow, inside the click handler. I use `$(this).closest('.slideshow')` to get the closest parent slideshow to the clicked image.

Working version below:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6PX22/6/

```
$(function () {
    $('.slideshow').each(function () {
        // Instance of slideshow
        var $slideshow = $(this);
        // Set count of images in slideshow
        $slideshow.find('.images-counter').text($slideshow.find('img').length);
        // Hide all but first image
        $slideshow.find('img').not(':first').hide(0);
        // Store the current image as data on the slideshow
        $slideshow.data('data-image', 0);
    });

    $('.slideshow img').click(function (e) {
        // Find the parent slideshow
        var $slideshow = $(this).closest('.slideshow');
        // Get the images of that slideshow
        var $images = $slideshow.find('img');
        // Get current image from data - could also get from visibility of image
        var currentImage = $slideshow.data('data-image');
        // Get count of images
        var imagesCounter = $images.length;
        // Hide the current image
        $images.eq(currentImage).hide(0);
        // Increase the counter and wrap at the end
        currentImage = currentImage >= imagesCounter - 1 ? 0 : currentImage + 1;
        // Save the current image number
        $slideshow.data('data-image', currentImage);
        // Show the new image
        $images.eq(currentImage).show(0);
        // Set the text to match the count
        $slideshow.find('.current-image-counter').text(currentImage + 1);
        // Set the text to match the description in the image
        $slideshow.find('.slideshow_comment').text($images.eq(currentImage).attr("alt"));
    });
});
```

Comment: hm, I'll try it, but it doesn't work on JSFiddle link that you attached, try to click on images.

Comment: The first example was missing some $instance references... fixing now

Comment: in your example there is some error (on JSFiddle), as you can see all of images visible in the same time, also I tried it in my code and it doesn't work as it must work like in this example for single slideshow :( http://jsfiddle.net/6PX22/

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit to make it more obvious what it does and made sure everything works. Try the new link.

Answer (score 0):

You are using one function to the same elements on your page. Create instance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function with 1 parameter which will mean id of slider. Then create a wrapper for each slider and send its ID to the function.

```
$(function() {
    nextSlide('slider_wrapper1');
    nextSlide('slider_wrapper2');
});
function nextSlide(id)
{
var currentImage = 0;
id = "#"+id;
    $(id + '.slideshow img').not(':first').hide(0);
    var imagesCounter = $('id + .slideshow img').length;
    $('id + .images-counter').text(imagesCounter);
    $('id + .slideshow_comment').text($('id + .slideshow img').eq(currentImage).attr("alt"));

    $('id + .slideshow img').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('id + .slideshow img').eq(currentImage).hide(0);
        currentImage = currentImage >= $('id + .slideshow img').length-1 ? 0 : currentImage+1;
        $('id + .slideshow img').eq(currentImage).show(0);  
    $('id + .current-image-counter').text(currentImage+1);

    $('id + .slideshow_comment').text($('id + .slideshow img').eq(currentImage).attr("alt"));
    }); 
}
```